# About how to use array to make a meteor tag app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

After read the discovermeteror, I want to make a tags app.

It will be like how Stack Overflow's questions are tagged.

So, my code is:

```
Tags.insert ({ food : ['apple','hotdog','meat','bean']});
food = function () { return Tags.find() }
your food is<span class=＂tag＂> {{food}}</span>
```

However, all tags will appear in one tag.

What should I do to divide them?

Answer (score 0):

each accepts arrays too not only cursors

```
{{#each food}}
   <span class=＂tag＂> {{this}}</span>
{{/each}}

food = function () { 
      return Tags.findOne({yourselector}).food;    
}
```

or

```
  {{#each alltags}}
      {{#each food}}
          <span class=＂tag＂> {{this}}</span>
      {{/each}}
  {{/each}}

    alltags = function () { 
          return Tags.find();    
    }
```

Here is the working [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/uPFDQbefBAvaoTFsg/Leaderboard), you can see how they are sorted on a `<ul>` element, just to show how they are not *siameses twins*

Comment: Thanks,but there have another question .If i use ' Tag.insert({cook:'jake',food :['meat','bread']}) ' The code will break

Comment: can you please add the code to yur question or create a meteorpad, The data that your inserting, there is no chance of break.

Comment: sorry，i am a fresh in markdown，so i use github～the URL is github.com/kimielven/meteortags

Comment: move common.js ,main.html and style.css files to client folder, it will work

Comment: what does completely mean? what issues you're facing?

Comment: i want to let cook.name and many food use one collection ,and let them to appear in one page .but i find if i use <each>,the food name will disappear.Sorry , my English is poor